# Passing array and got: ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm developing the front-end of a crud application on angular, and i got this error when passing an array:

> ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

How can i solve the error?

Here's my method to list the cities:

```
listar(pagina:number = 0){
    this.filtro.estado = this.estadoSelected.name;
    this.filtro.page = pagina;
    this.cidadeService.listar(this.filtro).subscribe(data => {
      const contentKey:any = Object.values(data)[0];
      const registros:any = Object.values(data)[2];
      this.totalRegistros = registros;
      this.cidades = contentKey;
      console.log(Array.isArray(this.cidades))
      console.log(this.cidades);
    });
  }
```

This is what i get from `console.log`

[image]

Any type of help is very appreciated

Comment: Please show the HTML template that triggers the error. Also what does the variable `this.cidades` initially before it's assignment in the subscription callback.

Comment: It's template related error (*ngFor, used with non-iterable variable)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but i solved already :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an different component for the table, so I solved the problem putting an @Input on the table.component.ts to receive the value of my array 'cidades'

table.component.ts:

`@Input() tabela!: any[];`

table.component.html:

`<p-table [value]="tabela" ...`

cities.component.html

`<app-tabela-cidades [tabela]="cidades" [size]="filtro.size"></app-tabela-cidades>`

Answer (score 0):

ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff ''. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

In my case, I had a custom component that was included in the Form Group.
The error was that instead of the standard value in the Form Group is a string instead of an array as expected.

```
const formGroup: any = {
  tags: [''], <--
};
this.generatorForm = this.fb.group(formGroup);
```

So the form is trying to compare something with a string instead of an array.
To fix this I just added an array there.

```
const formGroup: any = {
  tags: [[]], <--
};
this.generatorForm = this.fb.group(formGroup);
```